# IBM-Worklight: Failed starting project

Tags: java, ldap, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere, worklight-server

I added the mobilefirst runtime environment to the configuration. In the Server Configuration Tool, the runtime environment is displayed and running. But my new runtime environment is not displayed in MobileFirst Operation Console. The following errors are displayed in the logs:

> [17.11.18 3:15:26:218 MSK] 0000002e
>   com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator      E
>   FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /RusGidroMobileSD
>   [project RusGidroMobileSD]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL
>   [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/RusGidroMobileSD/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService'
>   while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in
>   URL
>   [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/RusGidroMobileSD/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while
>   setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL
>   [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/RusGidroMobileSD/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'com.digdes.rusgidro.mobilesd.ldap.ldapProviderUrl' in string value
>   "${com.digdes.rusgidro.mobilesd.ldap.ldapProviderUrl}"    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>     at
>   com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator.loadSpringConfiguration(JeeProjectActivator.java:467)
>     at
>   com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator.access$400(JeeProjectActivator.java:57)
>     at
>   com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator$1.run(JeeProjectActivator.java:223)
>     at
>   com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator.contextInitialized(JeeProjectActivator.java:280)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2388)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1048)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6404)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:446)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:441)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:761)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startModule(WebContainer.java:739)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.app.manager.web.internal.WebModuleHandlerImpl.deployModule(WebModuleHandlerImpl.java:106)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModule(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:574)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModules(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:484)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:431)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.app.manager.war.internal.WARApplicationHandlerImpl.install(WARApplicationHandlerImpl.java:73)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction.execute(StartAction.java:139)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.enterState(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.run(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:779)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in
>   URL
>   [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/RusGidroMobileSD/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while
>   setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL
>   [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/RusGidroMobileSD/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'com.digdes.rusgidro.mobilesd.ldap.ldapProviderUrl' in string value
>   "${com.digdes.rusgidro.mobilesd.ldap.ldapProviderUrl}"    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>     ... 34 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL
>   [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/RusGidroMobileSD/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'com.digdes.rusgidro.mobilesd.ldap.ldapProviderUrl' in string value
>   "${com.digdes.rusgidro.mobilesd.ldap.ldapProviderUrl}"    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>     ... 44 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not
>   resolve placeholder
>   'com.digdes.rusgidro.mobilesd.ldap.ldapProviderUrl' in string value
>   "${com.digdes.rusgidro.mobilesd.ldap.ldapProviderUrl}"    at
>   org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:173)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:241)
>     at
>   com.worklight.server.bundle.api.WorklightConfiguration.parseStringValue(WorklightConfiguration.java:191)
>     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean.resolveValue(LoginConfigurationServiceBean.java:698)
>     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean.getMap(LoginConfigurationServiceBean.java:685)
>     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean.createInstance(LoginConfigurationServiceBean.java:611)
>     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean.processLoginModules(LoginConfigurationServiceBean.java:216)
>     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean.afterPropertiesSet(LoginConfigurationServiceBean.java:156)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
>     ... 51 more

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have an adapter deployed, that is throwing an uncaught exception when it is trying to initialize as part of runtime synchronization. See this:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Could not resolve placeholder 'com.digdes.rusgidro.mobilesd.ldap.ldapProviderUrl' 
in string value "${com.digdes.rusgidro.mobilesd.ldap.ldapProviderUrl}
```

You should resolve this error or have appropriate exception handling in place - ensure the exception is caught.